# Tips to reduce the execution time of this Matlab loop containing several matrix operations

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, optimization, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to evaluate the matrices `Y(p,k)` and `Z(p,k)` using the following simplified Matlab code.

They depend on some matrices `A(j,k)`, `B(j,p)` and `C(j,k)` which I am able to precalculate, so I have just initialised them as random arrays for this MWE. (Note that B is a different size to A and C).

```matlab
Nj = 5000;
Nk = 1000;
Np = 500;  % max loop iterations

A = rand(Nj,Nk);  % dummy precalculated matrices
B = rand(Nj,Np);
C = rand(Nj,Nk);

Y = zeros(Np,Nk); % allocate storage
Z = zeros(Np,Nk);

tic
for p = 1:Np
   
    X = A .* B(:,p);
    Y(p,:) = sum( X , 1 ); 
    Z(p,:) = sum( C .* X , 1 );
    
end
toc    % Evaluates to 11 seconds on my system
```

As can be seen above, I am repeating my calculation by looping over index `p` (because the matrix `B` depends on `p`).

I have managed to get this far by moving everything which can be precalculated outside the loop (contained in A, B and C), but on my system this code still takes around 11 seconds to execute. Can anyone see a way in Matlab to speed this up, or perhaps even remove the loop and process all at once?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following should be equivalent and much faster:

```matlab
Y = B' * A;
Z = B' * (A.*C);
```

*Notes:*

- If `B` is complex-valued then you should use `.'` for transposition instead.
- You may also want to pre-compute B directly in transposed form (i.e. as a Np by Nj matrix) to avoid the transposition altogether.
- If C is not needed anywhere else, then pre-compute it as `A.*C` instead in order to avoid the extra element-wise multiplication.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. Just a follow up out of curiosity - is this just something you pick up with Matlab experience, or is there a trick to spot when these full vectorisation techniques can be used to replace loops, and how to do it?

Comment: I would say from experience coding with a piece of paper or whiteboard nearby; often when you write the maths down, these simplifications jump out at you.

Comment: Just to take the magic out of it, there are a couple of things that stood out. First, sums of element-wise products are inner-products, and if there is a loop around it looks a lot like a matrix product. In general loops of inner products are easy to vectorize, loops of outer-products not so much. Second, looking at the size of the inputs & outputs, it looks a lot like a matrix product if somehow `j` was in the "middle", so transposing B seems like a good thing to do. You might also want to look at Numpy's `einsum`, it's pretty nifty, although Matlab doesn't have that.

Comment: I see, thanks Jonathan. I will try to write the terms down on paper to see it explicitly, and be on the lookout for opportunities to put it into practice in my other codes! Thanks for the solution and advice.